# How to have the result of "cargo release" also pushed to a GitHub release?

Tags: github, rust, release, rust-cargo

I'm writing a [command line program](https://github.com/Riduidel/rrss2imap) using Rust and Cargo. To manage releases, I've found the excellent [release](https://github.com/sunng87/cargo-release) Cargo plugin.

I want, in a Maven release fashion, to have the compiled versions of my crate available in a GitHub release. How can I do that? As a bonus, if I can have the [git journal](https://github.com/saschagrunert/git-journal) release notes published, it would be excellent.

Comment: look more like a request than a question.

Comment: @Stargateur well, prior to enter an issue, I would prefer to ask if a solution already exists.

Comment: Are you sure you really want that? AFAIKT, Maven is mostly used for Java and its offspring, which means that the compiled thing is some bytecode and is usable wherever JVM is ported to. But Rust's compiler makes native binaries, so you'll have to cross-compile to a number of architectures to have a decent coverage. Nevertheless, it is interesting to see if this can be done.

Comment: There are projects that do release binaries to Github, so maybe take a look at how they are doing it? [Ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) is one of them. If you can't figure out how the release process works, just file an issue and ask – BurntSushi is usually very repsonsive and happy to answer questions.